# How to map value type to keys of react state in reducer's function parameters?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Say I have an initial state like this:

```
const initialState = {
  hasError: false,
  counter: 0,
  token: [...Array(2)].map(() => ''),
};
```

and a reducer function, that consumes and updates the state, like in the [offical example](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) (modified to include `action.value` instead of `state.count`):

```
const initialState = {count: 0};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return {count: action.value + 1};
    case 'decrement':
      return {count: action.value - 1};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Counter() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {state.count}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'decrement', value: 1})}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'increment', value: -1})}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

How can I make this function resolve the type of `action.value` from `action.type`?

For example:

```
const reducer = <K extends keyof typeof initialState>(state: typeof initialState, action: { type: K; value: typeof initialState[K] }): typeof initialState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'hasError': {
      return {
        ...state,
        hasError: action.value, // here the type should be `boolean`
      };
    }
    case 'token': {
    return {
      ...state,
      token: action.value, // type should be `string[]`
    }
   // etc...
  }
};
```

I also tried something like this, to no avail:

```
type TypeResolver<K> = Extract<TypeMap[keyof TypeMap], { state: K }>['valueType'];

type TypeObject<K extends keyof typeof initialState> = { state: K, valueType: typeof initialState[K] };

type TypeMap = {
  error: TypeObject<'hasError'>;
  resend: TypeObject<'resendEnabled'>;
  timerIteration: TypeObject<'timerIteration'>;
};

const reducer = <K extends keyof TypeMap>(state: typeof initialState, action: { type: K; value: TypeResolver<K> }): typeof initialState => {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to narrow the type of `action.value` by checking the value of `action.type` because they are both *generic types*.

We can rewrite the function signature in a way that makes the `action` parameter a *discriminated union* which can be narrowed.

```
const reducer = (
    state: typeof initialState, 
    action: { 
        [K in keyof typeof initialState]: { type: K, value: typeof initialState[K] } 
    }[keyof typeof initialState]
): typeof initialState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'hasError': {
      return {
        ...state,
        hasError: action.value, // here the type should be `boolean`
      };
    }
    case 'token': {
      return {
        ...state,
        token: action.value, // type should be `string[]`
      }
    }
    default: {
        return state
    }
  }
}
```

This would not change the way you are calling the reducer function.

```
reducer(initialState, { type: "hasError", value: true })
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmOU4EMA2BlKKoFMYC8MA3gFAwwAWKEAogE70j0BcMAZuhLgDTkygArmDysYABj4UoIANa4wbANoA6NQEFGKAJ4AKAEwBKALoqAtigAOu3YcIA+GAHInhvgF8A3KVKhIselwAE0FgXHpCGF1+CmgcXDYobUtcEHZ4RGR0LHieGBiYFGBkcDZifIpKyqUAaQyYeW00mCSU5oQkVExsPGMyluSEmBq8gDd0QSHW1PSOrO742uMYdwrK9yVG5un2zK6c3tJDRMHdzuye-AJHMliAdyRgSiiikrAVabtbyuAafCdqHRGMwnGUChRAlBBPQwCRwZU1Co4ngpFVKoCGEwxK84OAVOM0JM8gB6YlUcL4KCUSmDGAQSggQRoIIwABG+AABqyQCA0LgUGAOfCvAV3AVftxnDJ5GBQXC0TBIdDYd8FYjkbx4dI5Ao2Di8QSiTBSQMUnSGUyWeyYBzoPQEABzJTGIUKsVVd2VIK4ThMqBghUQ3BQmF0y6i-hisWkQIhML0XRzfaXPLlaZsABEGOB9AzYwmU3okxWhiAA)